# Python 2.7: How to check if row already exists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to check if a row already exists. If it doesn't, something has to be written in the row. My CSV file is always empty.

```
# import libraries
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# integer for first article id
articleid = 4449
articles = 4459

while articleid < articles:
    # specify the url and article id
    url = 'http://www.bkfrem.dk/default.asp?vis=nyheder&id='+str(articleid)
    articleid += 1
    # query the website and return the html to the variable
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

    # parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable soup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    # create CSV file
    csvfile = csv.writer(open('news.csv', 'a'))

    # take out the <div> of name and get its value and text
    title_box = soup.find('h1', attrs={'style': 'margin-bottom:0px'})
    title = title_box.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    date_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'style': 'font-style:italic; padding-bottom:10px'})
    date = date_box.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    articleText_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'news'})
    articleText = articleText_box.text.encode('utf-8').strip()

    # print the data (encoded) to the CSV file
    with open('news.csv', 'rb') as csvfileO:
        f_reader = csv.reader(csvfileO, delimiter=',')
        for row in f_reader:
            if articleText not in row:
                csvfile.writerow(["Title", "Date", "Text"])
                csvfile.writerow((title, date, articleText))
```

What am I doing wrong since it's empty?

Comment: It looks like you are opening the same exact file twice. `'news.csv'`

Comment: `if articleText not in` - ???

Comment: Typo. Haved edited the code :)

Comment: @JacobIRR: Yes, one is to append, and the other is to read in binary mode. Is that incorrect?

Comment: I'm suspicious of it being incorrect, but not 100% sure. I would try using two files to see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
for row in f_reader:
    if articleText not in
        csvfile.writerow(["Title", "Date", "Text"])
        csvfile.writerow((title, date, articleText))
```

You have `if articleText not in`

Not in what? You should have it pointing to something to validate.

```
if articleText not in "Something":
     csvfile.writerow(["Title", "Date", "Text"])
     csvfile.writerow((title, date, articleText))
```

Comment: What you spotted is most likely a typo that could not have caused the described behavior.

Comment: Probably, but I've encountered issues like these in the past that would leave me scratching my head for awhile wondering why it's not working.

Comment: Nonetheless, your answer does not really answer the OP's question and should have been posted as a comment.